# run onnx yolov7 model in python

Tags: python, pytorch, yolo, onnx, inference

I am trying to run an onnx model on python but everytime I have a runtime error saying expected input is different from given.
I am using the following code and I would be happy if somebody has a hint or an idea:

```
from PIL import Image
import onnx
import torch
from PIL import Image
import torchvision.transforms as transforms

img = Image.open("test (2).jpg")

resize = transforms.Resize([640, 640])
img = resize(img)

img_ycbcr = img.convert('YCbCr')
img_y, img_cb, img_cr = img_ycbcr.split()

to_tensor = transforms.ToTensor()
img_y = to_tensor(img_y)
img_y.unsqueeze_(0)

onnx_model = onnx.load("best.onnx")
onnx.checker.check_model(onnx_model)
session = rt.InferenceSession(
"best.onnx", providers=[ 'CPUExecutionProvider'])
session.get_modelmeta()
ort_inputs = {session.get_inputs()[0].name: np.array(img_y, dtype=np.float32)}
ort_outs = session.run(None, ort_inputs)
img_out_y = ort_outs[0]

img_out_y = Image.fromarray(np.uint8((img_out_y[0] * 255.0).clip(0, 255)[0]), mode='L')

# get the output image follow post-processing step from PyTorch implementation
final_img = Image.merge(
"YCbCr", [
    img_out_y,
    img_cb.resize(img_out_y.size, Image.BICUBIC),
    img_cr.resize(img_out_y.size, Image.BICUBIC),
]).convert("RGB")

# Save the image, we will compare this with the output image from mobile device
final_img.save("./runs/detect/my_exp/test (2).jpg")
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: what model are you using? It may be related to the fact you are trying to use only Y channel but the model expects 3 channels (RGB) instead of 1.

Comment: Oh yes you are right my model uses RGB. I am trying to debug and fix the code but I am still facing some problems and can't understand why the model is expecting 4 and not 3 dimensions though I trained on RGB images. The error is: [ONNXRuntimeError] : 2 : INVALID_ARGUMENT : Invalid rank for input: images Got: 3 Expected: 4 Please fix either the inputs or the model.